# 1 has_many:.., :through and 1 has_and_belongs_to_many: .. problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

The following are the models and association.

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address_attributes
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :clients, :through => :campaigns
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :vendors, :through => :campaigns
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :vendor_id, :client_id, :start_date, :end_date
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :vendor
end
```

And this is the new campaign create form
    - form_for @campaign do |f|
      = f.error_messages
      %p
        = f.label :name
        %br
        = f.text_field :name
      %p
        = f.label :client_id, "Client"
        %br
        = f.collection_select(:client_id, Client.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Please select the client"}, {:class => "client_list"})

Now, the association method `@vendor.clients` will just list the clients through the `campaign` join model.
If the campaign table is blank, there ain't any `clients` I can get with `@vendor.clients`

But as you see in the `collection_select` in the new campaign form, I have to be able to choose the clients that belong to the vendor. So, I had to put the `Client.all` call.
Though it renders the collection select, all those clients will be listed though they don't belong to that vendor.

So, to get/create/associate the clients and vendors with each other and to get `@vendor.clients` though the `campaign` is not created, I had to add another many to many association between vendors and clients, right?

If I do create the habtm association, it will conflict with each other, right?

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address_attributes
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :clients, :through => :campaigns
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :vendors, :through => :campaigns
  has_and_belongs_to_many :vendors
end
```

How am I gonna solve this? coz now, if I do, `@vendor.clients` or `@client.vendors`, which association gets called?

The one with `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many: .., :through => ..`

Comment: BTW, Milisami, you should improve your response rate ;) You hardly comment/vote/say anything when someone answers you qs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename your associations. In Vendor model:

```
has_many :campaign_clients, :through => :campaigns, :class_name => 'Client', :source => :client
```

and in Client model:

```
has_many :campaign_vendors, :through => :campaigns, :class_name => 'Vendor', :source => :vendor
```

Then, for example, `vendor.clients` will trigger the *habtm* association, and `vendor.campaign_clients` will trigger the *:through* association.

Comment: Now with that association I'm in trouble when creating a new campaign with the @vendor in scope. The client_id never gets filled in. Here is the pastie. http://pastie.org/1019836 At line 8 of Console output, the client_id is nil??
Do I have to change anything in the Campaing's belongs_to: association?

Comment: And on the log file, there is a warning about the mass assignment for the client model?